# Hibernate "could not get next sequence value" oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

i get this error `could not get next sequence value` when I try to save this Entity with Hibernate:

```
package beans;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "EVGENY")
public class Article {
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ArticleGen", sequenceName="ARTICLESEC")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator= "ArticleGen")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;
    @Column(name="postat")
    private String postat;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private UserAcc user;

    public Article(){
    }

    Get Set...      

}

insert into article (title) values('asdfaf');
```

in Oracle SQL Developer this `insert into article (title) values('asdfaf');` works well.

if i set id variable explicitly ( `Article a = new Article();a.setId(3);` )
everything is OK. I double checked the name of the sequence.

Comment: Are you able to select the next sequence value when logged in as the same user that Hibernate is connecting with?

select ARTICLESEC.nextval from dual;

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have another entity that works perfectly with it's sequence. I will try to use new sequence, to restart the database and to rewrite the entity. Hope something will work

Answer (score 1):

Check user permissions on the sequence. Most of the time it is grant issue

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of reasons to get this exception. Maybe you can check the questions and give me some more details about your problem:

- check if the 'hibernate.dialect' is set to Oracle?
- permission on sequence ok (schemata, select etc.)?
- is there some trigger behind the table and throwing plsql error?
- some other plsql that could break the insert?
- is the transaction broken?
- was there an exception (sometimes silent) somwhere before the call of create (like stale state or out of bounce) so that transaction is marked for rollback?
- is there a connection is erroneous error before exception?
- is the entity maybe already attached (check with contains)?
- do you use spring or another framework where you can add exception resolvers or translators?
- which version of oracle database do you use? 10 or 11? and are the used drivers correct?
- is there a findSingle call before that does not return any value?